# how does  compare two different type of objects in scala?

Tags: scala, floating-point

When i am checking values inside scala interpreter like:

```
scala> 1==1.0000000000000001

res1: Boolean = true

scala> 1==1.000000000000001

res2: Boolean = false
```

Here I am not getting clear view related with "how does scala compiler interpret these  as integer or floating points or doubles(and comparing)" .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not really Scala related, it is more of a [ieee-754](/questions/tagged/ieee-754) floating-point arithmetic issue. First of all when comparing `Int` with `Double` it will cast `Int` to `Double` (always safe). The second case is obvious - values are different.

What happens with the first case is that `Double` type is not capable of storing that many significant digits (17 in your case, 64-bit floating point can store up-to 16 decimal digits) so it rounds the value to `1`. And `1 == 1`.